# Run Docker Image in Local Machine with fetching .env variables from the Hashicorp-Vault server

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, devops, hashicorp-vault

We are using the HashiCorp-Vault for credentials and parameters management of the Node-JS and Java Applications.

As we are using the docker images of the NodeJS and Java applications.

Now the credentials that are saved in the HashiCorp-Vault are injected into the Images using **SideCar** in Kubernetes pods. The Application is working as expected.

Now the issue comes in when we want to run the application(DockerImage) on the local machine How we can inject the Credentials and Parameters from the Hashicorp-vault server.?

Their are several CURL API (https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/kv/kv-v2) that can be used but how we can inject the data into the DockerImage.

Please share the way how can we inject the Credentials and parameters to the docker image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

curl -H "X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_TOKEN" -X GET  "$VAULT_ADDR/v1/$VAULT_DJANGO_DB/$ENV" | jq .data.data > $CONFIG_PATH/django_db.json

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to run the application in a raw docker container on your local machine, or could you instead run it in a simple local k8s cluster (e.g. minikube)?
If you can continue to use k8s, then you can continue to use the sidecar.